# create components inside a for loop in react

Tags: reactjs

i have this and it doest work, i have no console problems, and it doesnt show anything in the screen

```
function App() {
  var users = [new TestimonioUser("Emma Bostian","emma","Software Engineer","Spotify","'I've always struggled with learning JavaScript. I've taken many courses but freeCodeCamp's course was the one which stuck. Studying JavaScript as well as data structures and algorithms on freeCodeCamp gave me the skills and confidence I needed to land my dream job as a software engineer at Spotify.","Sweden"),
                 new TestimonioUser("Sarah Chima","sarah","Software Engineer","ChatDesk","freeCodeCamp was the gateway to my career as a software developer. The well-structured curriculum took my coding knowledge from a total beginner level to a very confident level. It was everything I needed to land my first dev job at an amazing company.","Nigeria"),
                 new TestimonioUser("Shawn Wang","shawn","Software Engineer","Amazon","It's scary to change careers. I only gained confidence that I could code by working through the hundreds of hours of free lessons on freeCodeCamp. Within a year I had a six-figure job as a Software Engineer. freeCodeCamp changed my life.","Singapore")];
  return (

    <div className="App">
      <div className="contenedor-principal">
        <h1>Here is what our alumni say about freeCodeCamp:</h1>
        {users.forEach(user => {
          <Testimonio
          name={user.name}
          country={user.country}
          image={user.image}
          occupation={user.occupation}
          description={user.description}
          business={user.business} />
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i want to show 3 users

Comment: Instead of `users.forEach()` you want `users.map()` example: `users.map(user => <Component user={user} />)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues. One is you can't use `.forEach` to output DOM inside the `return ()` block. You can run that before the return and push those items into an array to display like `{domItems}`.

Another way is to use `.map` within a `return ()` block.

Additionally, your iterator is not returning your `Testimonio` component. It's just calling it. You need a `return ()` inside the iterator.

So even with .map that would be a problem:

```
{users.map(user => { // <--- now you must return() something!
  <Testimonio
  name={user.name}
  country={user.country}
  image={user.image}
  occupation={user.occupation}
  description={user.description}
  business={user.business} />
})}
```

You can simply use:

```
{users.map(user => (
  <Testimonio
  name={user.name}
  country={user.country}
  image={user.image}
  occupation={user.occupation}
  description={user.description}
  business={user.business} />
))}
```

This is the same thing just more verbose but also allowing for further action to happen within your loop:

```
{users.map(user => {
  return (
    <Testimonio
    name={user.name}
    country={user.country}
    image={user.image}
    occupation={user.occupation}
    description={user.description}
    business={user.business} />
  );
})}
```

It's also unclear what `TestimonioUser` is doing so further refactor may be necessary here. However, this is the best way to iterate and output DOM inside of React return blocks.